# ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again

Tags: java, oracle

I used soap as a web service and I connect with oracle

in my application I have this config in applicationContext-db.xml file

```
 <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
```

but some time I have this error :

```
06:05:58,239 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: null
06:05:58,239 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Closed Connection
06:05:58,244 ERROR [JDBCTransaction] JDBC rollback failed
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again
```

in this case I should restart my jboss server

**Updated :**

I added `<property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>`  but I have the same error  related to **maximum idle time**

this error appeared when I did not invoke the Web service for a period

I try also to modify same parameters in my config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>


      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.12:1521/testSID"/>
        <property name="username" value="test"/>  
        <property name="password" value="test"/>
         <property name="maxActive" value="1500"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1000"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="20000"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="3600"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I think that I should  modify the config of idle time in oracle and not only in my application .

I think that I should make the idle time **UNLIMITED** for the user **test** and change **resource_limit**

but I did not know how to do this configuration in Oracle and ask if there are other config to be done in oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `testWhileIdle` property to `true`.

You can also check the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) for the other details.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question, but I have the same error, I think that I should make same config in oracle